# PPTX module - looping through paragraphs to find/replace text but only replaces 1st instance

Tags: python, python-pptx

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm using a find and replace function to loop through shape objects in Powerpoint using pptx module. When I call this function, it only replaces the 1st occurrence of the text (which happens to be the title). I suspect the issue is this current code ONLY replaces the first occurrence of the text or won't parse through the entire shape object and is looking for shapes that contain ONLY the full searchable text.

Code is found here:
`

```
def search_and_replace(search_str, repl_str, input):
    """"search and replace text in PowerPoint while preserving formatting"""
    prs = Presentation(input)
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.placeholders:
            print('%d %s' % (shape.placeholder_format.idx, shape.name))
            if shape.has_text_frame:            
                if(shape.text.find(search_str))!=-1:
                    text_frame = shape.text_frame
                    cur_text = text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].text
                    new_text = cur_text.replace(str(search_str), str(repl_str))
                    text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].text = new_text
    prs.save(input)
```

`

I tried printing the shape objects and it looks like they are showing up properly.

Comment: What happens if you iterate backwards? You're probably modifying the tree in a way that stops the iteration. (I think I've been caught out by this one.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget text frames can have multiple paragraphs and runs

```
for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
```

Comment: To that point, a match might be across two or more runs.